# How do I check the input data type of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I have one doubt about how to check the data type of input variables in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a,b;
    cout<<"Enter two double values";
    cin>>a>>b;
    if()        //if condition false then
        cout<<"data entered is not of double type"; 
        //I'm having trouble for identifying whether data
        //is double or not how to check please help me 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If the input cannot be converted to a double, then the `failbit` will set for `cin`.  This can be tested by calling `cin.fail()`.

```
 cin>>a>>b;
 if(cin.fail())
 { 
     cout<<"data entered is not of double type"; 
 }
```

Update: As others have pointed out, you can also use `!cin` instead of `cin.fail()`.  The two are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

That code is hopelessly wrong.

1. `iostream.h` doesn’t exist. Use `#include <iostream>` instead. The same goes for other standard headers.
2. You need to import the namespace `std` in your code (…). This can be done by putting `using namespace std;` at the beginning of your `main` function.
3. `main` **must** have return type `int`, not `void`.

Concerning your problem, you can check whether reading a value was successful by the following code:

```
if (!(cin >> a))
    cout << "failure." << endl;
…
```

Comment: (The numbered points are now fixed as they distracted from the actual question)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if my memory serves, the following shortcut should work:

```
if (! (cin>>a>>B)) { handle error }
```